# I got error in TMX in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have made Backgd.tmx using TmxTileMap.and i am trying to use it in my implementation as below

```
   CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"Backgd.tmx"];
    [self addChild:tileMap];
```

but i got error as like

```
-[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: Images/background.png

 cocos2d: Couldn't find file:Images/background.png
```

Comment: Have You added background.png in your Resource Folder ? If Not then try it by putting it over there.

Answer (score 1):

Tiled saves the (relative) path to image files. But in Xcode, the directory structure is flattened hence there is no `Images` folder.

I suppose your tileset is in a `Images` subfolder of the folder containing the tmx file. You can either:

- move the tileset images to the same folder as the tmx file (and update in Tiled accordingly or by editing the tmx file with a text editor)
- add the Images subfolder to your Xcode project as a folder reference (blue icon) rather than as a group (yellow icon) - **note:** this will always add **all** files in that folder to the app bundle, this may not be desirable if you also keep other files (ie photoshop source files) in the `Images` folder or its subfolders
- change cocos2d's TMX reader code to use only `lastPathComponent` of the tileset filename strings